# Salesforce Opportunity Kanban View grayed out

Tags: lightning-experience, kanban

We have an issue with the Opportunity Kanban view, it’s displaying few records grayed out irrespective of the path value (Pic attached below). 
Went through a blog (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iS3EQAU)  where the reason was mentioned as multiple path in the SObject (Opportunity here) but could not get much info there to resolve the issue.
Anyone has faced this issue before pls let me know.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analysis we found that the records where User is having 'Read-only' access will appear as gray in KANBAN view. Users can not edit or move this record in KANBAN view.
Had a discussion with the Salesforce Support and sooner they will be updating their articles on KANBAN view related to grayed out observation. 
Most probably updated Article will be available on or after 14th March 2018.